# Replacement of release in sdk 5

Tags: ios, ios5, release

Can anybody tell me about the replacement of "release" in ios-sdk5

e.g. `[myview release];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using ARC, there is no more release. The ARC will take care of retain/release/autorelease for you.

To migrate your old project to ARC, you can go to Edit=>Refactor-> Convert to Objective-C ARC on Xcode 4.2